# Can I ask a question about setting up a profiling application for debugging on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, scope

I'm not sure if the question I want to ask is proper for Stack Overflow. I'm having trouble using Xdebug to profile a PHP application in PHPStorm using a vagrant machine.

I want to ask a question posting screenshots and my configuration, to see if someone can help.

This is not a programming question, but a configuration question. Is this a proper question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: See Cupcake's answer for the facts, but let me just say that we need more questions and answers about debugging, be it methods or tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a question about programming tools, which is specifically stated as [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Just make sure that your question still meets the other [quality guidelines for good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).